# Pausing a Thread When GPIO Input Interrupt Triggers using Event.set() Inside a Thread Class Method

Tags: python, multithreading, events, interrupt, thonny

Good day everyone, Im trying to call a method inside a thread class which should set an event flag inside that thread, resulting in the thread to stop running while the event is set. The current code kind of works, and calls the function, but the event flag does not seem to trigger inside the thread.

The thread is responsible for an operation to run when a button is pressed on the GUI, but it shouldn't run if the event is set.

A minimal version of my code:

```
import threading
import time

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD.UP)

global run = 0

class Pump_Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval=0.5):
        super(Pump_Thread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.interval = interval
        Pump_threads = threading.Thread(target=self.run, daemon=True)                           
        Pump_threads.start()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()
        print("Things have stopped yo...")

    def resume(self):
        self._stop_event.clear()
        print("And Now Things will resume")
    
    def run(self)
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            if (run == 1):
                #doing some stuff when bit set#
                print("Yeah Yeah, I'm running")

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       #Some Initializing methods to load buttons and graphics
       self.start_btn=tk.Button(self,height=32,width =80,command=self.Start)
       self.start_btn.place(x=50, y=50)
       self.reset_btn=tk.Button(self,height=32,width =80,command=self.Reset)
       self.reset_btn.place(x=50, y=80)

  def Start(self):
      global run
      run = 1 #<------Set Bit for code to run

  def Reset(self):
      d = Pump_Thread()
      d.resume() #<-----Run Method inside thread
      

class Monitor_Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval=0.5):
        self.interval = interval
        Monitor_Threads = threading.Thread(target=self.Monitor_Thread, daemon=True)                           
        Monitor_Threads.start()

    def run(self)
        while True:
            if Condition == True:
                d = Pump_Thread()
                d.stop() #<-----Run Method inside thread

class Interrupt_Class(page):
    def Input(self):
        d = Pump_Thread()
        d.stop() #<-----Run Method inside thread

    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=Input, bouncetime=300)

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, *kwargs)
        super().__init__()

        p1 = Page1(self) #Other Pages Added here with navigation buttons to raise the page to the front of the GUI#
        p1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.TK()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    Thread1 = Pump_Thread()
    Thread2 = Monitor_Thread()
    root.mainloop()
```

When the interrupt is triggered, "Things have stopped yo..." is printed, so the method is called, but the process still starts when the GUI Button pressed, meaning the event didn't set. What would be the reason for this?

Comment: Ok, now that I can see `Pump_Thread` being instantiated, what does `target=self.Pump_run` mean? Surely this produces an error?

Comment: Ok, you are using `target=self.run`, but this is implicit when deriving from `Thread`. See my other answer.

Comment: Sorry, that is just a typo when reducing the code for the Question. The Code is about 1400 lines and runs without error or warnings, but the focal part for the question is the new addition as to why the Event doesn't set with when the method is called from another class. It produces no errors or warnings, and print the message but the event is not set. Yet when the method is called inside the class, the event is set

Comment: Yes, the `stop` and `resume` methods `set` and `clear` the `threading.Event`, but only for the instance being referred to. When you call `stop` and `clear` you should be referring to the `Thread1` instance created just before `mainloop()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have many mistakes piled on top of one another.

You need to look at the many examples on stackoverflow of how to create and manage threads.

You might try something like this:

```
class Pump_Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval=0.5):
        super().__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.interval = interval

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()
        print("Things have stopped yo...")

    def resume(self):
        self._stop_event.clear()
        print("And Now Things will resume")
    
    def run(self)
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            print("Yeah Yeah, I'm running")

# other parts elided

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.TK()
    main = MainView(root)

    Thread1 = Pump_Thread()
    Thread1.start()
```

but now all other places which need to start and stop `Pump_Thread` need access to `Thread1`. So you should pass this into objects that are created.

```
class Interrupt_Class(page):
    def __init__(self, pump):
        self.pump = pump
    def Input(self):
        self.pump.stop() #<-----Run Method inside thread

ic = Interrupt_Class(Thread1)
```

Comment: Understood, The use of objects ,i'll admit, is confusing, i expected the Event to be similar to a boolean which you can set inside the class by simply calling the method inside the class from anywhere else

Comment: Yes, it is similar to a boolean, but a boolean which is *per instance*. Your `run` variable is a global, which would work across all instances, but you must know that, as a programmer, you must try very, *very*, **very** hard *not* to use globals.

Comment: A horrible truth indeed, the confusion between instance and class variables have fooled me more than once already. But in this case the use of globals is beneficial because the bit is monitored on various pages to show if it True or Not, and its only changed by user interaction. Could you please explain what `ic = Interrupt_Class(Thread1)` does?

Comment: I meant it to mean that you are passing the reference `Thread1` into an instance of `interrupt_Class` so it would have `self.pump` refer to the correct instance of `Thread1` and subsequently `self.pump.stop()` would do what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling:

```
d = Pump_Thread()
```

each time before calling: `d.stop()` which only makes that thread stop.

How is `Pump_Thread` instantiated and where do you store the reference to it?

In fact, you don't show how any of your classes are instantiated.

Comment: Sorry , Didn't expect it to be necessary for the reduce code version. I am fairly new to the language so making simple mistakes or misunderstanding the new terms is fairly common for me.